# SQLite update fields with replacing words

Tags: sqlite

I'm not good in SQLite, so there came the question: how can I update certain column from fields like `/media/Soft/furtherpath` to `/media/username/Soft/furtherpath`? 
The problem is that after updating to ubuntu 12.10 from 10.10 I can't get my shotwell library work, as newer ubuntu uses `/media/username/...` for mounting somehow.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE some_table
SET certain_column = substr(certain_column, 1, 6) ||   -- /media
                     '/username' ||
                     substr(certain_column, 7)         -- /Soft...
WHERE certain_column LIKE '/media/%'
```